# Streaming L.711 m-Law Audio using RTP

Tags: c#, audio-streaming, rtp

I'm new in audio streaming.

I have a stream of audio data, encoded into G.711 m-Law format (from a 3rd party device). And I need to provide an access to it via RTP protocol.

Could you advise me some free library, which would allow me to create a RTP server and feed it with my data?

Everything I found seems to be a RTP client but not a server.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 1):

I would use libVLC with a C# wrapper (like https://github.com/videolan/libvlcsharp).
Depending on your source audio format - you may need a μ-law audio encoder. Which should be pretty straight forward to implement or find.